# Hiding chatter feed in service cloud console

Tags: javascript, service-cloud-console

We have a requirement to hide the chatter feed for Accounts for service cloud console users.  The chatter feed is  contained within two divs on the Account page, with ids 'feedLinks' and 'chatterfeedshell'.  So I thought I could do this by writing a custom console component as follows:

```
<apex:page >
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.parent.document.getElementById('feedLinks').style.display = 'none' ;
      window.parent.document.getElementById('chatterfeedshell').style.display = 'none' ;
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

However, this seems to have an issue with cross domains, because the VF page has a domain of  'c.cs9.visual.force.com'.  Does anyone have any idea on how to get round this?

Thx,
Hamayoun

Comment: I need to do the same thing. Technical support says that it's not possible and open a request in ideas.salesforce.com. Maybe it could help if you voted up my idea in Salesforce.com and they might put it in a future release. Turning off chatter doesn't work in Service Cloud. I'm trying to fire some javascript at the application level to hide DOM objects as a solution now, but not having much success. Looks like you're trying the same idea.

Comment: Yes Steve, that's what I am trying to do.  I can do it outside Service Console using home page components, but within Service Console there seems to be no way of putting javascript such that it stays in the same domain.

Answer (score -2):

Do all of the service cloud console users have the same profiles or a limited number of profiles that are unique compared to non-service cloud console users? If so, it appears to me as though what you desire could be done through profiles. I'd refer you to the [Chatter REST API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/salesforce_chatter_rest_api.pdf) for more details on what you can and can't do with Chatter. There's a great deal of information on filtering feeds, User Profiles, and other things. You can access it and much more from the [Chatter_API page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Chatter_API) which has many other resources you might find helpful to you.

Comment: chatter is enabled or disabled per organization. there is no current way to limit it to a subset of profiles.

Comment: I agree that it's enable or disabled per org, but the rest doesn't match with what I read in the API's. Its clear that individual users can readily be restricted. It was my impression it could also be done using profiles too. It may be a case of requiring additional thought on how best to implement it (e.g. one strategy might be to use filters to eliminate all feeds).

Comment: can you link to the doc that says it can be enabled to a subset of users? one thing to also consider is that if you hide chatter in the web ui, it will still be available in the api